# Word Cloud for Other Languages

Tags: javascript, persian, word-cloud, farsi

I using [JasonDavies's Word Cloud](https://www.jasondavies.com/wordcloud/) for my project, but there is a problem that I using Persian[Farsi] Strings and my problem here that words have overlapping in Svg.

This is my project's output:

[image: This is my project's output]

What happened to the Farsi words?

Comment: @Paul R, thanks for edit.

Answer (score 4):

As explained on the [About page for the project](https://www.jasondavies.com/wordcloud/about/), the generator needs to retrieve the shape of a glyph to be able to compute where it is "safe" to put other words. The about page explains the process in much more detail, but here's what we care for:

1. Glyphs are rendered *individually* to a hidden `<canvas>` element.
2. Pixel data is retrieved
3. Bounding boxes are derived
4. The word cloud is generated.

Now, the critical insight is that in Western (and many other) scripts, glyphs don't change shape based on context often. Yes, there are such things as ligatures, but they are generally rare, and definitely not *necessary* for the script.

In Persian, however, the glyph shape will change based on context. For non-Persian readers, look at ی and س which, when combined, become یس. Yes, that last one is *two* glyphs!

The algorithm actually has no problem dealing with Persian characters, as you can see by hacking the demo on the about page, putting a breakpoint just after the `d.code` is generated, to be able to modify it:

[image: source of bbtree.js on the about page, with a breakpoint at line 129]

Replacing it with `1740`, which is the `charCode` for the first Persian glyph above, and letting the algorithm run, shows beautiful and perfectly correct bounding boxes around the glyph:

[image: render of ی and its bounding boxes]

The issue is that when the word cloud is actually rendered, the glyph is placed in context and... changes shape. The generator doesn't know this, though, and continues to use the old bounding data to place other words, thus creating the overlapping you witnessed. In addition, there is probably also an issue around right-to-left handling of text, which certainly would not help.

I would encourage you to take this up the author of the generator directly. The project has a GitHub page: https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud so opening an issue there (and maybe referring back to this answer) would help!

Comment: thanks for answer. But i don't know to do? What's My solution?!

Comment: As I said at the bottom, go to that link, which is the project page, open an issue with a description of your problem and a link to this question, and wait for the author to get back to you.

Comment: And if you do not want to wait, you will have to figure out how to _fix the software_. Your problem is interesting… but that also means it cannot be solved simply. Effort will need to be spent.

Comment: JasonDavies don't answer to my problem, and I'm in a hurry.

Comment: Well then _effort will need to be spent_. In other words, _fix it_. Or possibly, go use another tool. Or **pay** a developer to fix it for you. Telling people that you are in "a hurry" and doing _nothing_ to help is not how things happen.

Comment: @FélixSaparelli I'm impress with how you kept your cool ;-) and your answer